# Trying to understand rejection sampling on this example with a rough solution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I find rejection sampling very hard to understand and there is also not much about it on the internet, imo. So I found an example with a solution and can you explain the steps I don't understand / wrong please?

> Create random numbers from this density by using rejection sampling
>
> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{3}{4}(2x-x^2)&\mbox{if } x \in(0,2) \\  0 &
> \mbox{else}\end{cases}$$

The algorithm works like that: We have that $M:= \sup_{x}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}<\infty$

1. Simulate $U \sim U(0,1)$
2. Simulate $Y \sim g$
3. Accept $X=Y \text{ if } U \leq \frac{1}{M}\frac{f(Y)}{g(Y)} \;\text{ else to to 1. }$

Solution: Find a function $g$ that is easier to sample from, such that there is a $M \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $Mg(x) \geq f(x) \; \forall x \in (0,2)$.

Pick $g \sim U(0,2)$, then we have that $M:= \sup_{x \in (0,2)}f(x)=\frac{3}{4}$

$\color{red}{\text{Now sample from $U(0,1)$ for which you get $U=0.32$}}$ and then sample from $\color{red}{Y \sim q \Rightarrow 1.28}$. Now the sampled $y$ value from step $2.$ needs to be accepted if $U \leq \frac{1}{M} \frac{f(Y)}{g(Y)}$, so we have that $0.32 \leq \frac{4}{3}f(1.29)=0.92$ and thus we accept $X=1.28$

---

I especially don't understand the red market text, how do you get $U=0.32$ and what is $\frac{f(Y)}{g(Y)}$. I really hope you can tell me because I looked this up on several pages and it's just too complicated and I think an example is much better for understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part in red is just an example.  It's saying suppose we sample from $U(0,1)$ and the result is $0.32$.  Next, suppose we sample from $U(0,2)$ and the result is $1.28$.  So $0.32$ and $1.28$ are assumed to be two random numbers drawn from the appropriate distributions for the purpose of illustration.

For $0 \le Y \le 2$ we have $f(Y) = (3/4) (2Y-Y^2)$ and $g(Y) = 1/2$, so
$$\frac{f(Y)}{g(Y)} = \frac{(3/4) (2Y-Y^2)}{1/2}$$

However, I do not understand the part of the example where it says $M = 3/4$.  It appears to me that $M = 3/2$.  The equation $M = \sup_{x \in (0,2)} f(x)$ should also be
$$M = \sup_{x \in (0,2)} \frac{f(x)}{1/2}$$
because $g(x) = 1/2$ for $x \in (0,2)$.  So I think there is an error in the solution.

Comment: You're right. The error in the text comes from the defintion of $$M$$, that should be $$M = sup_x f(x)/g(x) $$ ..

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for clarification. This will help me a lot for future and also in the exam I write tomorrow. Will definitely reward with bounty! :-)